# Is there a way to move a Google file to a folder with the same name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am very new to using google scripts.  I'm looking for a way to move files from my drive to folders with the same name.

Here is the code I tried using, but it comes up with an error - "Cannot use this operation on a shared drive item".

```
function sortFiles() {
//  var folders = Drive.Files.list({
//    "q": "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false",
//    "fields": "items(title, id)"
//  });
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();  
//  var files = Drive.Files.list({
//    "q": "mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false",
//    "fields": "items(title, id)"
//  });
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  var folderIDs = [];
  var folderNames = [];
  var fileIDs = [];
  var fileNames = [];

  do {
    var folder = folders.next();
    folderNames.push(folder.getName());
    folderIDs.push(folder.getId());
  } while (folders.hasNext());

  do {
    var file = files.next();
    fileNames.push(file.getName());
    fileIDs.push(file.getId());
  } while (files.hasNext());

  for (var i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < folderNames.length; j++) {
      if (folderNames[j].search(fileNames[i]) > -1) {
        var oldFileParents = DriveApp.getFileById(fileIDs[i]).getParents();
        DriveApp.getFolderById(folderIDs[j]).addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(
          fileIDs[i]));
        if (oldFileParents.hasNext()) {
          do {
            oldFileParents.next().removeFile(DriveApp.getFileById(fileIDs[i]));
          } while (oldFileParents.hasNext());
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want?  Are you saying that you want to move all of you files from your drive to folders on your google drive that have the same name as the files?

Comment: Yes.  For example, I want to move a file named "Julianna" from My Drive to a subfolder named "Julianna".

Comment: Are all of the files in the same folder or sub folders of a folder?

Comment: If the folder names do not exist do you want to create them?

Comment: The files are created from a template and automatically put in My Drive.  I want the script to take all the files in My Drive not currently stored in a folder, match the file name to a subfolder, then move that file into that folder.

Comment: The folders are already created.

Comment: Are all of these files google-apps-script files?

Comment: I don't know... they are all either doc files or sheet files.

Comment: Okay so they are either google documents or google spreadsheets files

Comment: And just to be clear all of the files you wish to move are in the root of myDrive correct?

Comment: Absolutely, yes

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation

Comment: Since the folders are all created have you collected all of their id's into a list perhaps in a spreadsheet because it would speed up the process if we could look up the id of a folder in a hash table rather than getting folders by name

Comment: No list.  Let me see if I can do that.

Comment: If all of the folders are in the same parent folder if would be easy to make a list with a recursive script.  I said easy but not necessarily fast.

Comment: All the folders are in the same parent folder.

Comment: So first step I would make a spreadsheet that has all of the subfolder names in one column and all of the id's in the next column by recursing through all of the subfolders in that parent and save all of the names and id's of all of the sub folders.  Then I'd use the table from that information in the next step

Comment: With the item in question, are you the owner?  The error message may imply that your account might not have the right permissions.  Check the shared drive share link and make sure your account is there.

Answer (score 1):

#### This will build your table of names and ids

```
function getsfn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1obWyAZl0vDlwbNqcGBq7Nt38qzusWt1d');
  getsfldrs(folder);
}

var level = 1;
function getsfldrs(folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder()) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0')
  const subfolders = folder.getFolders()
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    let subfolder = subfolders.next();
    sh.appendRow([subfolder.getName(),subfolder.getId()])
    level++;
    getsfldrs(subfolder);
  }
  level--;
}
```

#### This should move the files

```
function moveFilesInRoot() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const n2f = {};
  vs.forEach(r => n2f[r[0]] = r[1]);
  let folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  let docs = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  let shts = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (docs.hasNext()) {
    let f = docs.next();
    let name = f.getName();
    if (n2f.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      f.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(n2f[name]))
    }
  }
  while (shts.hasNext()) {
    let f = shts.next();
    let name = f.getName();
    if (n2f.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      f.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(n2f[name]))
    }
  }
}
```

You can goto to [Google Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference) and using the search box find any function that you don't understand. If it's a pure JavaScript function the go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

I just created a couple of files of the correct type and tested the code and it works for files of type MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS and MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendRow' of null
getsfldrs @ Code.gs:14
getsfn @ Code.gs:5

Comment: Well you will have to change the id and possibly the sheet name or at least create the sheet.  Some thought on your part is required.

Comment: I changed the id to the id of the parent folder, and created a sheet named ID.

Comment: @YuriKhristich you already have an answer I take it.  That's okay. I just like writing code and learning new stuff.  It's the human interaction that drive's me nuts.

Comment: When I execute, I get an error message - TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDataRange' of null  Where should I add the

Comment: That means your sh is null so either you sheet name is wrong or there isn't a sheet with that name in your active spreadsheet

Comment: Just so that you know I just tested the current code and it works for me with my last revision to the code that moves the files.

Comment: Thanks for helping so much.  The code now runs with no error message, but it's not moving my file.  I was able to get the first code to rune - I now have a spreadsheet with  all the possible destination folder IDs.

Comment: Please show me you current code.  Keep in mind it only moves docs and spreadsheets

Comment: Here's a link to a doc where I copied the current code.  I wish I could share the original spreadsheet with you, but I am a school administrator and it's a list of my teacher's names, etc.  Confidentiality problems!          Link to doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1euYa3VZL7COU4nzmNa0XiWUGpMU2JBl_Wr5BGw-a_Vg/edit?usp=sharing